# How Secure to Use ScriptableObjects in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

ScriptableObjects very fun to use and usefull for like items, data containers, inventory etc and supports JSON stuff. But as you can crate file in the root folder .asset file and using it, I wonder how secure to use them? 
Does it easily to hack or manipulatable from users? 
Does it secure to use in online or multiplayer games?
Should I use them in unity MMO game architecture design pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ScriptableObjects in Unity, but for online games it's best to assume that client is hackable (if not already hacked). If you're using it as container to send data over the server then it's fine, just don't trust whatever data comes in it without proper validation.

Comment: Thanks for reply! But my question is all about scriptableobjects :)

Comment: @T.Aoukar I think you are mistaking this tag as unity-container tag. This is a game engine and different from unity-container.

Comment: @Cemuka Always assume that any data stored on the client can be hacked, not even if it has been cryptographically secured. Never ever trust the client application: the client is a lying, cheating, bastard. Take the input data the client seems and always check: is this a valid action? If not, ignore the data.